# Despite many examples online, I cannot get my MATLAB repmat equivalent working in python

Tags: arrays, matlab, python-2.7, numpy, tile

I am trying to do some numpy matrix math because I need to replicate the repmat function from MATLAB. I know there are a thousand examples online, but I cannot seem to get any of them working.

#### The following is the code I am trying to run:

```
def getDMap(image, mapSize):
    newSize = (float(mapSize[0]) / float(image.shape[1]), float(mapSize[1]) / float(image.shape[0]))
    sm = cv.resize(image, (0,0), fx=newSize[0], fy=newSize[1])
    for j in range(0, sm.shape[1]):
        for i in range(0, sm.shape[0]):
            dmap = sm[:,:,:]-np.array([np.tile(sm[j,i,:], (len(sm[0]), len(sm[1]))) for k in xrange(len(sm[2]))])
    return dmap
```

The function getDMap(image, mapSize) expects an OpenCV2 HSV image as its **image** argument, which is a numpy array with 3 dimensions: `[:,:,:]`. It also expects a tuple with 2 elements as its **imSize** argument, of course making sure the function passing the arguments takes into account that in numpy arrays the rows and colums are swapped (**not**: x, y, **but**: y, x).

**newSize** then contains a tuple containing fracions that are used to resize the input image to a specific scale, and **sm** becomes a resized version of the input image. This all works fine.

#### This is my goal:

The following line:

`np.array([np.tile(sm[i,j,:], (len(sm[0]), len(sm[1]))) for k in xrange(len(sm[2]))])`,

should function equivalent to the MATLAB expression:

`repmat(sm(j,i,:),[size(sm,1) size(sm,2)])`,

#### This is my problem:

Testing this, an OpenCV2 image with dimensions **800x479x3** is passed as the **image** argument, and **(64, 48)** (a tuple) is passed as the **imSize** argument.
However when testing this, I get the following *ValueError:*

> dmap = sm[:,:,:]-np.array([np.tile(sm[i,j,:], (len(sm[0]),
>   len(sm[1]))) for k in xrange(len(sm[2]))])
>   ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with
>   shapes (48,64,3) (64,64,192)

So it seems that the array dimensions do not match and numpy has a problem with that. But my question is what? And how do I get this working?

Comment: repmat is seldom needed in Numpy-using code, as the same function is provided by broadcasting in a more general way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 calculations match:

```
octave:26> sm=reshape(1:12,2,2,3)
octave:27> x=repmat(sm(1,2,:),[size(sm,1) size(sm,2)])
octave:28> x(:,:,2)
   7   7
   7   7


In [45]: sm=np.arange(1,13).reshape(2,2,3,order='F')
In [46]: x=np.tile(sm[0,1,:],[sm.shape[0],sm.shape[1],1])
In [47]: x[:,:,1]
Out[47]: 
array([[7, 7],
       [7, 7]])
```

This runs:

```
 sm[:,:,:]-np.array([np.tile(sm[0,1,:], (2,2,1)) for k in xrange(3)])
```

But it produces a (3,2,2,3) array, with replication on the 1st dimension. I don't think you want that `k` loop.

What's the intent with?

```
 for i in ...:
     for j in ...:
         data = ...
```

You'll only get results from the last iteration.  Did you want `data += ...`?  If so, this might work (for a (N,M,K) shaped `sm`)

```
np.sum(np.array([sm-np.tile(sm[i,j,:], (N,M,1)) for i in xrange(N) for j in xrange(M)]),axis=0)

z = np.array([np.tile(sm[i,j,:], (N,M,1)) for i in xrange(N) for j in xrange(M)]),axis=0)
np.sum(sm - z, axis=0)  # let numpy broadcast sm
```

Actually I don't even need the tile.  Let broadcasting do the work:

```
 np.sum(np.array([sm-sm[i,j,:] for i in xrange(N) for j in xrange(M)]),axis=0)
```

I can get rid of the loops with `repeat`.

```
sm1 = sm.reshape(N*M,L)  # combine 1st 2 dim to simplify repeat
z1 = np.repeat(sm1, N*M, axis=0).reshape(N*M,N*M,L)
x1 = np.sum(sm1 - z1, axis=0).reshape(N,M,L)
```

I can also apply broadcasting to the last case

```
x4 = np.sum(sm1-sm1[:,None,:], 0).reshape(N,M,L)
# = np.sum(sm1[None,:,:]-sm1[:,None,:], 0).reshape(N,M,L)
```

With `sm` I have to expand (and sum) 2 dimensions:

```
x5 = np.sum(np.sum(sm[None,:,None,:,:]-sm[:,None,:,None,:],0),1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it thanks to your explanations. I didn't fully comprehend what should be going on inside the arrays. Ironically, just after implemting the solution, I found out that there is a function numpy.matlib.repmat() that does exactly what I want.. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: That `matlab.repmat` ends up doing a whole string of `reshape` and `repeat`s:  `a.reshape(1, a.size).repeat(m, 0).reshape(rows, origcols).repeat(n, 0)`

Comment: The Octave version of `repmat` uses `reshape`s and `ones (1, p)`.  `reshape` adds or consolidates dimensions, `ones` expands selected dimensions.

Comment: I found a symmetry to the problem using broadcasting that `repmat` obscures.

Answer (score 2):

`len(sm[0])` and `len(sm[1])` are not the sizes of the first and second dimensions of `sm`. They are the lengths of the first and second row of `sm`, and should both return the same value. You probably want to replace them with `sm.shape[0]` and `sm.shape[1]`, which are equivalent to your Matlab code, although I am not sure that it will work as you expect it to.

Comment: You were right about the dims. I could have used np.size() to do that.